# Efficient mapping of a function with multiple arguments along an axis of an ndarray

Tags: python, performance, apply

I have two `ndarray`s—one for the `values` and the other for the `weights` (derived from errors on `values`). I'm interested in obtaining the average and standard deviation along `axis=1` for the `values` ndarray. For clarity, here is a toy construction that does this task.

```
values=[[0.25,0.34,0.28,0.54],[0.23,0.38,0.29,0.55],[0.21,0.36,0.31,0.56]] 
errors=[[0.02,0.01,0.03,0.01],[0.01,0.02,0.03,0.01],[0.04,0.03,0.01,0.02]] 

def invsqerr(x):
    return 1/x**2

weights=np.apply_along_axis(invsqerr, 1, errors)


def wavg_std(y_arr, invsqerr_arr):
    average = np.average(y_arr, weights=invsqerr_arr)
    variance = np.average((y_arr-average)**2, weights=invsqerr_arr)
    return (average, math.sqrt(variance))


for k in range(len(values[0])):
    print (wavg_std([i[k] for i in values], [i[k] for i in weights]))
```

Output:

```
(0.23285714285714285, 0.009331389496316869)
(0.34897959183673471, 0.015681120581468193)
(0.30545454545454542, 0.009875254992000192)
(0.54666666666666663, 0.006666666666666672)
```

In my case `len(values[0])` (refer to the for loop) is of the order of a few million. The `for loop` doesn't seem to be the right approach for such large arrays.

An efficient method, perhaps, based on `np.apply_along_axis` for multiple arguments is sought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one efficient solution to this problem that makes use of Python 3's `multiprocessing` module.

Firstly, I transposed the ndarrays `values` and `weights`:

```
values=np.stack(values).transpose()
weights=np.stack(weights).transpose()
```

Then made use of `starmap`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(wavg_std, zip(values, weights))
```